# json_encode turns string to null

Tags: php

I have posts that save with html tags from a wysiwyg editor.

I want the json output to be stripped of all html tags.

Because strip_tags can sometimes remove the text, I'm using preg_replace like so:

```
$body = $row['content'];        
//$body = strip_tags($body);
$body =  preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $body);
$regex_strip_tags = "/<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>/";
$body = preg_replace($regex_strip_tags, '' , $body);
```

stash it in an array:

```
$arr[] = array('body' => $body);
```

The problem is that when I `echo json_encode($arr)` some entries appear `null` but if I use `print_r($arr)` I see everything as intended.

Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: does it literally say "null", or is it maybe just the html being RENDERED by the browser you're displaying it in? do a 'view source' in the browser to confirm...

Comment: `json_last_error_msg()` returns a string if a problem occurred.

Comment: @MarcB It is `null` ( confirmed by viewing source )

Comment: Are you passing non utf-8 strings to `json_encode` ?

Comment: @jonbaldie Im on PHP 5.4 so thats not available to me =( . David:  Not sure what you mean, its DATATYPE is LONGTEXT in MySQL

Comment: `json_last_error()` will work then.

Comment: @jonbaldie Did not return anything

Comment: All string data you pass into `json_encode` must be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @DavidDomain You are BOSS. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to UTF-8 encode your string data before passing it into `json_encode`.
Here is some more information on that.

[PHP json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).